# Dispay video from serveur to ios

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Hi everybody im using S3 service in amazon web service i do the following code to get my data video from server:

```
S3GetObjectRequest  *getObjectRequest  = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:video1 withBucket:@"videoFolder"];

        S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];
```

then i do :

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:getObjectResponse.body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString autorelease]];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

after i do this i got a black screen, if you have any suggestion pleaze help me

Comment: what is your media file attributes ( as in resolution , bitrate and format -mp4 etc)

Comment: my file is different type of  videos extention (mp4,mov....)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at this link. Not all the videos formats are supported by all iOS.

[enter link description here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html)

Go through the video technology part. Also, check if you have required permission for accessing the video file , because if it is authenticated_read access , then you will have to pass signature, expire and awsaccesskey with the url of the video. If it is public_read then no need for signature and all.

Answer (score 0):

Video hosting is possible via s3 service but streaming or downloading of video files is not possible from the s3 services. The s3 service doesnt have a mime type for video to give back to the client.